# special characters instead of alphabets

Tags: java

```
public class sixdighall {

    public static char k = 65;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String userin = "111111";
        int max = 180;

        String allofem = "";

        int a[] = { 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 12, 21 };
        for (int k1 = 0; k1 < a.length; k1++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                if (i < 100) {
                    String num = "" + String.format("%02d", i);
                    String added = userin + a[k1] + num;
                    allofem = allofem + added;
                }
                if (i >= 100) {
                    int b = 0;
                    while (b < 10) {
                        String added = userin + a[k1] + k + b;
                        allofem = allofem + added;
                        b++;
                    }
                }
                k++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(allofem);
    }
}
```

I want the order to be in the below format

Result should be

```
1111110100
1111110101
1111110102
.
.
.
.
1111110199
11111101A0
11111101A1'
.
.
.
.
.

11111101B1
```

But i am getting special characters instead of alphabets

```
111111100 111111101
.
.
.
.
111111199 1111111¥ 01111111¥
```

This program prints the numbers till max
Please help guys

Dummy text
"Nothing more to say,just adding some text"

Comment: what is the problem? where are the results stored? in `allofem` String? what do you mean "alphabets"?

Comment: please update with whole code.

Comment: i am getting 1111111¥0 instead of 11111101A0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `k++` at the bottom of your code.
When the program enters `i >= 100` your variable has already reached the value 165 and is not 65 anymore (or A). The char value 165 and above translates to those special characters.

Your code should look more like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String userin = "111111";
    int max = 180;

    String allofem = "";

    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 21};

    for (int k1 = 0; k1 < a.length; k1++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (i < 100) {
                String num = "" + String.format("%02d", i);
                String added = userin + a[k1] + num;
                allofem = allofem + added;

            }
            if (i >= 100) {
                int b = 0;
                while (b < 10) {
                    String added = userin + a[k1] + k + b;
                    allofem = allofem + added;
                    b++;
                }
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(allofem);
}
```

But this puts the problem only to a later point.
It is unclear what you want to achieve, so its not really possible to give a complete solution here.

Sidenote:

```
int a[] = { 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 12, 21 };
```

Is very dangerous because 01, 02, 03, 04, 05 are Octal Numbers. Somebody might miss this. They also dont help you in the sense of String Concatination (what you are doing), so its completly useless here.

Comment: i really doubt that :-D
As i said before, k will reach to specialcharacters at a later point.

Comment: 'for ( int i = 0; i < max&&s<max-100; i++)'     will do the work,where 's' gets increment each time the while loop is repeated